# cannot implicity convert list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get the check in status of employees but it is only letting me to return one of them, `First` or `FirstOrDefault` when i try to convert it to a list it's telling me:

> Cannot convert List<>  to ..Data.Entities.Checkinout

```
EmployeeCollection = (from userinfo in context.Userinfo
   join department in context.Dept on userinfo.Deptid equals department.Deptid
   where id == userinfo.Userid
   select new Employee()
   {
     Name = userinfo.Name,
     Department = department.DeptName,
     CardNumber = userinfo.CardNum,
     Status = userinfo.UserFlag.ToString(),
     ActualCheckinStatuse = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
         join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
         where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
         orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
         select new Checkinout
         {
           CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
           CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
         }).First()
   }
).ToList()
```

Comment: You mean where you assign `ActualCheckinStatuse` in the object initializer for `new Employee`? What is the declared type of `ActualCheckinStatuse`? If you change the `.First()` in the above code into `.ToList()` will the new type `List<Checkinout>` be something that is compatible with the declared type of the property?

Comment: Post the *entire* message, not just part of the message and `so on`. If it's a compilation error, it contains the exact line that caused the error. If it's an exception, it  will show what actually happened and the call stack will show *where* it happened. You can get the entire exception easily with `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: As for this error, it's pretty clear that you tried to *assign* an IQueryable<T> to a List property or field. Without the definition of the classes it's impossible to say what's wrong. Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes the list is not compatible with the type  im trying to display

Comment: How is EmployeeCollection declared? (what's its type?)

Comment: @johey it's a list of employees, whose attributes are fetched from a database and those i posted are some of them but the others are not needed for this type of convertion

Comment: You should be able to see what's happening if you break up the code in multiple blocks. 
e.g.  var step1 = your query; // now look what's the resulting type of step1
EmployeeCollection = step1.ToList();

That way you can see what's the result type of each step, so you may better understand the problem.

Comment: So is EmployeeCollection of type `List<Employee>` ?

Comment: @johey the employeecollection is already a list,but the checkinstatus only allows me to display the first item(e.g 20/1/2018 12:00PM)

Comment: @johey yes it is

Answer (score 0):

A part of your code looks like this:

```
       new Employee()
{
  Name = ...,
  Department = ...,
  CardNumber = ...,
  Status = ...,
  ActualCheckinStatuse = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
      join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
      where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
      orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
      select new Checkinout
      {
        CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
        CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
      }).First()
}
```

Here, the expression `(from checkinout in ... select new Checkinout { ... })` will be an enumeration (or sequence, if you prefer) of `Checkinout` instances. When you do `.First()` on that, as above, the result will be one instance of type `Checkinout`.

As far as I understand, that compiles well. And it is because the property `ActualCheckinStatuse` that you assign to in this initializer, has the same declared type, `Checkinout`.

If instead after this parenthesis `(from checkinout in ... select new Checkinout { ... })` you append `.ToList()`, then what you get is *all* those `Checkinout` instances in a .NET `List<>` in memory. Sure enough you cannot assign that to `ActualCheckinStatuse` because the types are not compatible. One `Checkinout` called `ActualCheckinStatuse` cannot be set to a whole `List<>` of such `Checkinout`s.

Comment: Do you know how could I display it as a list because if I make the ActualCheckinStatus to a list of Checkinouts I am unable to display it in my View due to another error : .. does not contain a definition for getenumerator